# transform javascript array combining child

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i go this json array

```
var responseArr = {options :{ch:["Hi", "By",], en:["Peter", "John"]}}
```

is it possible change into this form

```
var responseArrB = {"options": [{'ch':'Hi',en:'Peter'},{ch:'By',en:'John'}]}
```

i tried

```
let responseArrB = responseArr.options.ch.map( item => Object.assign({ch:item.ch, en:item.en}))
console.log(vv)
```

but responseArrB..show

```
{ch: undefined, en: undefined}
```

i could either show ch or en but can't combine it

```
let arrThree = responseArr.options.ch.map( item => Object.assign({ch:item, en:item}))
```

Comment: The second form is a syntax error, so no. Did you mean to put an array in there?

Comment: Maybe you mean `var responseArrB = {options: [{ch:'Hi',en:'Peter'},{ch:'By',en:'John'}]};`. An array of objects.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: [There is no JSON anywhere in your question](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and build a new array for each key.

```js
var object = { options: { ch: ["Hi", "By",], en: ["Peter", "John"] } },
    result = {
        options: Object
            .keys(object.options)
            .reduce((r, k) => (
                object.options[k].forEach((a, i) => {
                    r[i] = r[i] || {};
                    r[i][k] = a;
                }), r), [])
    };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you, Nina!, beside w3c and Mozilla, where can i learn more js, es6 pattern?

Comment: or you could just try to answer here some question on so.